# How GetKeyState works exactly?

Tags: windows, keylogger, getmessage

I have been struggling with understand how `GetKeyState` operating. I have done endless google searching and haven't yet managed yet to understand exactly how it works

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms646301(v=vs.85).aspx):

> The key status returned from this function changes as a thread reads key messages from its message queue.

Take a look at the following code. I didn't create a message processing loop. 65 represents the virtual key of the character 'A'.

```
while(true) {

    printf("the character %c, the vkey_state is %x", 
    MapVirtualKey(65, MAPVK_VK_TO_CHAR),GetKeyState(65) & 0x8000);
    Sleep(150);
}
```

I pressed "A" on the keyboard, **while being at the window console of my program**.
sometimes, the `vkey_state` value is `0x8000` as expected, sometimes not.

What exactly is happening under the hood? I didn't write any message-processing code, so i assume it is created automatically. When I press 'A', a [WM_KEYDOWN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646280(v=vs.85).aspx) is sent to my thread message queue. When I release the key 'A', a [WM_KEYUP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/he-il/library/windows/desktop/ms646281(v=vs.85).aspx) is sent to my thread message queue. other key-related messages might be sent in between. What happens when I call GetKeyState? when exactly it will set the MSB of its return value to '1'? When will it change back to 0? Is it related to the calls to GetMessage?

In Addition - what confused me the most - is when I switched to another program (cmd.exe), and I typed 'A', my program was able to monitor it while being in the background - but cmd.exe thread has another message queue - why does it work? However - it didn't work If I started cmd.exe in elevated mode (high integrity).

this contradicts the information I found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20190209010420/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041130-00/?p=37173).

> If the user has switched to another program, then the `GetKeyState` function will not see the input that the user typed into that other program, since that input was not sent to your input queue.

Comment: Raymond's blog post applies to programs that have a message queue.  Basically any program that uses CreateWindowEx() or GetMessage().  So *not* console mode apps, they don't create a window nor pump messages.  The console window is owned by a different process, conhost.exe.  That GetKeyState() seems to do *something* has been noted in other SO questions, but they all note that it is flaky.  Don't do it.

Comment: I am trying to understand how GetKeyState can be used for keylogging. From this experiment it seems to work globally. I know about GetAsyncKeyState which is useful too for keylogging. What do you mean by "SO" questions?